«А и может, так и есть» — знаки?
Максимум, что нам дано разглядеть, это некую погрешность улыбки, которую (погрешность) легко списать на камешек в ботинок попал, — а и может, так и есть?

А вокруг "камешек в ботинок попал" точно не нужны кавычки?

Спасиьо; мне не нужны.

Ну... Знаю, что редактирование авторского предложения — это чаще всего дело неблагодарное. Но — попробую.
✦ Я бы написала так:
Максимум, что нам дано разглядеть, — это некая погрешность улыбки, которую легко списать на «камушек в ботинок попал». А и может, так и есть?
(Или так: списать на камушек в ботинке.)
Рассуждения
• Поставила бы тире (максимум — это некая погрешность).
• Все-таки использовала кавычки («камушек в ботинок попал»).
Если без кавычек, то камушек в ботинке.
• Почему камушек? Мне кажется, что эта форма больше подходит для передачи разговорного стиля. Она помягче и мне ближе.
Камушек и камешек
• Вместо второго тире тогда ставлю точку.
• — А может, так и есть? — с надеждой взглянул на жену Корольков (Л. Дворецкий).
А может, так и есть? (у авторов Т. Мироновой, А. Ясинского, К. Колибри, Ю. Кузнецовой).
В конструкции "а и может, так и есть" первая "и" похожа на усилительную частицу. Думаю, что дополнительная запятая здесь не нужна.
